# Activating an NPN BC817 for a LED

Tags: bjt, npn, led-driver

I have voltage signal which is 0V-1V square wave and i desire to see it with a LED which will be on when 1V comes and be of when 0V comes. I used a BC817 npn and a LED (min:3V, max3.5V, 20mA). I am not sure whether 1V is enough to activate BC817. This is the [datasheet of BC817](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BC817_BC817W_BC337.pdf). If you share your idea, i will be happy. This is my circuit;

[image]

Comment: "I am not sure whether 1V is enough to activate BC817". Why are you not sure? Have you tried the circuit and seen that it doesn't work or are you just skeptical?

Comment: Because i could not find any chance to establish circuit. I have done only simulation.

Comment: The LED will turn on. If it is not bright enough, try making R2 smaller.

Comment: I will use 100Ω as input resistance, thank you.

Comment: I think 1mA into the base should be enough. I think around 400 Ohms should do it.

Comment: The gain of 10 is just ultra dultra worst case scenario. Some BJT's got a minimum gain of 10 (like a power BJT made for driving motors). Some other got a minimum of 30. So yeah, 400Ω as @mkeith proposes would **most likely** work. But it's weird that the datasheet doesn't say anything about the absolute minimum gain.

Comment: It says 100 is the minimum at Ic=100mA. And the gain curve suggests that there is not much variation in gain with different Ic.

Comment: @mkeith yes, 100 minimum gain at Ic = 100mA..... and..... **Vce... at 1V**, look around page 10, there will be some graphs you'll recognize. Ic vs Vce, look at Vce being small.

Comment: In those graphs, where you see IC going down, that is because the transistor is entering saturation and beta is degrading. Beta is reported at Vce = 1V, because at that voltage, the transistor is safely out of the saturation region. In this application, we want the transistor to saturate. If we want Ic to be 20 mA, then 1mA should be enough for Ib (forced beta of 20). But 2mA would be OK too, I guess. Forced beta of 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that \$V_{BE}\$ is around 0.7V. According to the datasheet, the minimum DC gain is 100. But that's when \$V_{CE}\$ = 1V. You will most likely saturate the transistor, and the DC gain gets really low in saturation. Well let's take the worst case scenario, DC gain = 10.

With 1 volt input and R2 = 1kΩ, the base current will be \$\frac{1V-0.7V}{1000Ω}=0.3\$mA. That means that \$I_{CE}\$ will be up to \$10×0.3\$mA \$=3\$mA.

I'll assume that \$V_{CE}=0.1\$V because it is in saturation.

With VDD = 5V and R1 = 150Ω, the \$I_{CE}\$ current will be \$\frac{5V-0.1V-3.5V}{150Ω}=9.3\$mA

\$9.3\$mA is greater than \$3\$mA. So it **looks** like you will need to reduce that 1kΩ to say 330Ω at least. I'd go for 200Ω to be on the safe side. This is assuming an absolut worst case scenario gain of 10. Your transistor might have 10.. or 30.. or more, so if the gain is 30, then the 1kΩ will suffice, but if you want to **guarantee** that it will work, then 200Ω will be enough. Because I've never seen any gain that is worse than 10 while being fully saturated.

Here's the [link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2050%0At%20672%20368%20704%20368%200%201%20-0.49484738747490653%200.6119294518061479%2010%0Ag%20704%20384%20704%20400%200%0Ar%20608%20368%20672%20368%200%201000%0Aw%20544%20368%20608%20368%202%0A162%20704%20288%20704%20352%201%204%201%200%200%200.01%0Ar%20704%20224%20704%20288%200%20150%0AR%20704%20176%20704%20128%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0AO%20704%20352%20784%20352%201%0Aw%20704%20176%20704%20224%201%0Aw%201024%20176%201024%20224%201%0AO%201024%20352%201104%20352%201%0AR%201024%20176%201024%20128%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%201024%20224%201024%20288%200%20150%0A162%201024%20288%201024%20352%201%204%201%200%200%200.01%0Aw%20864%20368%20928%20368%202%0Ar%20928%20368%20992%20368%200%20330%0Ag%201024%20384%201024%20400%200%0At%20992%20368%201024%20368%200%201%200.535738978497281%200.6356618543514236%2010%0A207%20544%20368%20544%20336%200%20square%0A207%20864%20368%20864%20336%200%20square%0AR%20544%20368%20512%20368%201%202%20100%200.5%200.5%200%200.5%0A) to a schematic in case you want to play around.

Comment: I think you miscalculated the base current. It will be (1-0.7)/1k = 300 uA. The LED should turn on. Might not be super bright.

Comment: I will use 100Ω as input resistance, thank you.

Comment: Even with R2=1k resistor transistor goes to saturation. Thus, R1 has around 1.5v (5v-0.1-3.xx), we like 20 mA => keep R2=1k, change R1 to 75 ohms, 100 ohms for safety.